# Printing Windows Form into A4 size page

Tags: vb.net, printform

I am creating a billing software.I need to print the invoice.Size of the invoice is A4.I am printing it using
**PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)**

Now the problem is:When I am printing, it is not printing the full windows form.Instead it is printing the currently visible area of the windows form.kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations you need to use Crystal Report in case of .NET and use JasperReport in case of Java.